# Unix script - String Validation

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I'm very new to Unix scripting (.ksh). I have to implement a functionality to check whether my argument says "welcome" present in an string array e.g.

`{"welcome","test","exit"}`

The logic is similar to `String.contains` in Java.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ksh or bash? (you have bash in tags)

Comment: @Stefanos Kalantzis its ksh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Following is in `bash`, you need to change it accordingly to `ksh`.

#### script

```
array=(welcome test exit)
string='welcome';
for item in ${array[*]}
do
    if [[ $string =~ .*$item.* ]]
    then
        echo "It's present!"
    fi
done
```

#### Output

```
It's present!
```

To iterate over arguments passed to a shell script, use for with empty in, that default the iteration over arguments, or `in '$@'`.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, you can [either upvote or accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45970/182516).